# Combine the same dataframe so every row is compared against every other row

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am trying to compare every row against every other row. I don't want to use apply as I need to be able to use the result later on and apply takes too long. This process currently takes less than a second using MySQL and would like it to take similar time in pandas.

The table at the beginning.

```
import pandas

columns = ["id", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]
table = [
    [1, 'test', 'a1', 100, "unspecified"],
    [2, 'test', 'a2', 200, "unspecified"],
    [3, 'test', 'a3', 300, "unspecified"],
]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=table, columns=columns)
```

Query in MySQL

```
SELECT *
FROM
db.df AS s1,
db.df AS s2;
```

The result I end up with due to this query, I want to end up with the same result but just using pandas or at least within python.

```
id  c1      c2  c3  c4          id  c1      c2  c3  c4
1   test    a1  100 unspecified 1   test    a1  100 unspecified
2   test    a2  200 unspecified 1   test    a1  100 unspecified
3   test    a1  300 unspecified 1   test    a1  100 unspecified
1   test    a1  100 unspecified 2   test    a2  200 unspecified
2   test    a2  200 unspecified 2   test    a2  200 unspecified
3   test    a1  300 unspecified 2   test    a2  200 unspecified
1   test    a1  100 unspecified 3   test    a1  300 unspecified
2   test    a2  200 unspecified 3   test    a1  300 unspecified
3   test    a1  300 unspecified 3   test    a1  300 unspecified
```

As you can see all the rows a recompared against each other. I am new to pandas and looking at the documentation I can't seem to find anything that will help me achieve this. Currently, I am going around this problem by starting a MySQL database in a docker container and running the process on there but it feels like a really long-winded way of doing it and makes it a pain for the automated tests. So is there a way to end up with the same results within pandas

Comment: you can look into `np.where` I don't think anyone will be nice enough to pick apart your query and re-write it in pandas, but you can easily write condtional statements in pandas using numpy : [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) oh and where are you getting your data from? is it coming from mysql?

Comment: I don't care much about the where condition but more about the first part of the query, Where all rows are compared against eachother
```
SELECT *
FROM db.df AS s1,
     db.df AS s2
```

Comment: I will edit the question for clarification

Comment: The question has now been edited, I hope it's more clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your MySQL query is the implicit, older version of `CROSS JOIN`, run the same cartesian cross product in pandas by merging on a key of same values:

```
cj_df = pd.merge(df.assign(key = 1), df.assign(key = 1), on = 'key')
```

And add a filter to avoid reverse duplicates and same row matches using `id` field:

```
cj_df = (pd.merge(df.assign(key = 1), df.assign(key = 1), on = 'key')
           .query("id_x < id_y")
           .drop(columns = ['key'])
        )
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a smart solution. 1 question, how come key column is not in the result? since it is a new column I would have expected it to be there

Comment: Great! Glad to help. And I drop *key* column with `drop` call.